# Maven slowdown taking 3,4 minutes after "[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 ..."

Tags: maven

My Maven system suddenly slows down, when I run with "-X" option, got this

```xml
[me@centos7 component]$ mvn -X
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_74, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_74/jre
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/<me>/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/<me>/.m2/repository
**[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /home/<me>/.m2/repository**
...
```

It stops for about 3,4 minutes after the line:

```
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /home/<myuser>/.m2/repository
```

Does anyone know what is going on ? Or how to investigate further why it is suddenly slowing down ?

Cheers, Tuan.

Comment: You wrote `suddenly` which implies before it has worked as expected and now it does not ..the question is: What has changed in the meantime?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I clean my local maven repository, and it doesn't stuck (for a few mins) after that line anymore. To answer your question: no changes to all maven settings file, or credentials to access the minors. My gut feeling is that some local artifacts are corrupted or having version messed up. A natural step is looking into EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager, to see what it does, but I didnt have time, and anyway it's ok now.

Comment: If you have the feeling that artifacts are corrupted than you should start to use [checksum policy](https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/). Version messed up is what?